# Prime ideal (Polynomial ring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I:=\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ be an ideal of the polynomial ring $R:=\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

How to show that $I$ is a prime ideal?

I tried this:

$I$ is a prime ideal if for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $ab \in I$, it's $a \in I$ or $b \in I$.

So let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $ab \in I$. Then:

$ab=r_1(x^2+1) \in I$, with $r_1 \in R$.

Now it should be $a=x^2+1$ and $b=r_1$.

Since $a \in I$ if $b=1$ it follows that $I$ is a prime ideal.

I'm not sure if this way to show it is correct. Or is there another method to show that it's a prime ideal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps an easier way:

Define $\;\phi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z[i]\;,\;\;\phi(f(x)):=f(i)\;$ , with $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ . Show this is a surjective homomorphism of rings and, of course, $\;\Bbb Z[i]\;$ is an integral domain. Of course, this happens iff the homomorphism's kernel is a prime ideal...

In fact, it is pretty common also to see $\;\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]=\Bbb Z[i]\;$

Comment: So $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \exists f(z) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\phi(f(z))=y$. Let $y=a+bi$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. But how to conclude that $\phi(f(z))=f(\sqrt{-1})=a+bi$ and therefore surjective?

Comment: The ring $\;\Bbb Z[i]\;$ is the ring of all integer polynomials in $\;i\;$, which is the same as to say that an element in $\;\Bbb Z[i]\;$ is of the form $\;f(i)\;$ , for some $\;f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ . There is your surjectivity...!